# R recycling process

Tags: r

Please see the snippet below:

```
x <- c(23,43,54,75,76,6,87,5,43,234,2)
y <- c(1,2,23,43,54,75,76,6,87,1)
z <- x + y
```

The snippet gives me the warning message.When I try to add x and y as:

```
#Warning message:
#In x + y : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

However When I add:

```
x <- c(3,4,5,8)
y <- c(1,3)
z <- x + y
z
```

No error message is thrown and R recycles it perfectly. Why?

Comment: 11 is not a multiple of 10 while 4 is a multiple of 2 (`library(fortunes); fortune(14)`)

Comment: See http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-lang/R-lang_41.html : "If one tries to add two structures with a different number of elements, then the shortest is recycled to length of longest. "

Comment: To those who voted to close: I don't see any typographical error in the post, and the situation is reproducible. This question can be useful for novice R users in the future.

Comment: @RHertel, hi, I voted to close because this question can be self-answered by reading the help pages (also the answer is in the warning message...); besides, in both situation, the vector is recycled, I don't think it needs a Q/A to see that when you recycle a 10-long vector to "match" a 11-long one, it won't perfectly fit. I don't believe it can help future readers, hence my close vote. But this is just my opinion...

Comment: @Cath Thank you for your response. I respectfully disagree. SO should not become an elitist forum where only the most complex and nowhere documented features are discussed. Its primary purpose is to help programmers, and this includes (in my opinion in particular) people who are beginning to learn. Besides, there might be a reason why SO does not provide an option to vote to close based on something that may or may not be self-evident.

Comment: @RHertel, likewise, I respect your position but cannot agree. The recycling feature is documented in multiple help pages and, like I said, the warning message is quite clear. SO is there to help, I totally agree but also asks for a "minimum research effort" from the OP. In this present case, there is, imho, none.

Comment: @RHertel, after some discussion and thinking, I retracted my close vote. I still think this question should have been self-solved by the OP. Trying to understand warning messages by oneself and reading manuals are necessary steps to learn something imo.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is important to notice that this is a **warning**, and not an **error**. So in either case, no error is thrown and the vectors are added.

Concerning the absence of the warning in your second example, the warning message states the reason quite clearly:

> object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

In your second example, the length of `x` is twice the length of `y`, so it *is* a multiple (in contrast to your first example, which yields the warning). Hence, no warning is given in the second example when the vector `y` is recycled.